# Vuejs passing options into a component

Tags: javascript, components, vue.js

I have a vue component, it's a slider.

```
<Slider
  images= ['img/da-slide1.png', 'img/da-slide1.png']
  bg = "#000000"
  speed = 1
>
</Slider>
```

I want to pass a variety of options in. I have tried the code above without any luck.

I also want to v-for the images out

```
<div v-for="item in images">
    {{ item }}
  </div>>
```

Can it be done?

Comment: great I got that, was just the syntax, but how do I v-for them out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass images array as property, note colon `:images`:

```
<Slider
  :images="['img/da-slide1.png', 'img/da-slide1.png']"
  bg="#000000"
  speed="1"
></Slider>
```

Also remember to declare prop in Slider component `props: ['images']`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
Vue.component( 'slider', {
 template: '<div class="slider" :style="cBackgroundColor">' +
   '<span v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="\'image\' + index">' +
     '<img :src="image.url" :alt="image.alt" :title="image.alt"/>' +
    '</span>' +
  '<div>',
 props: {
   images: { type: Array },
    backgroundColor: { type: String, default: "#000000" },
    speed: { type: Number },
  },
  computed: {
   cBackgroundColor: function() {
     return 'background-color: ' + this.backgroundColor;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
 el: "#app"
});
```

```css
.slider {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <slider
      :images="[{ url:'https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png', alt:'Vue.js' }, { url: 'https://www.codementor.io/assets/page_img/learn-javascript.png', alt:'Javascript' }]"
      background-color="#9b42f4"
      :speed="1">
    </slider>
</div>
```

When you pass properties to a component you must use "v-bind" or the shortcut ":" in case the properties is not a String :

```
my-prop="you pass string here" <== when no "v-bind:" or no ":" this is a string

:my-prop="you write here like in javascript"
:my-prop="myVariable" <== myVariable is a javascript variable
:my-prop="2" <== its the number 2 and not the string "2" !

:my-prop="'use single quote to use string' + maVariable"
:my-prop="[ 'array1', 'array2' ]"
:my-prop="{ 'prop1': 'value1', 'prop2': 'value2' }"
```

For the "v-for" use ":key". See [v2.2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.2.0?utm_campaign=Revue%20newsletter&utm_medium=Newsletter&utm_source=revue):

> When using v-for with a component, a key is now required. You will likely see a bunch of "soft warnings" when you upgrade, but this does not affect the current behavior of your app.